# Sublime Text 3 not reflectingchanges made to theme file

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, text-editor

I made a change to the `<key>lineHighlight</key>` `<string>#cccc</string>` in the .tmTheme file to change the highlight color of the current line, this worked just fine in the laptop I used at work but it just won't reflect the changes on my personal laptop or desktop for some reason, even tried to change it to a really bright color just to see if maybe my eyes where tired and I wasn't noticing the change but it stays the same, tried restarting and nothing happens, and I've been looking around with no luck.

Appreciate any assistance. If it helps I'm using Materialize theme and this is happening in a Windows and Linux machine.

Comment: I haven't used Sublime Text but just an idea: do other settings work? Are you positive it is using that configuration file? Some programs depending on how they were installed look for configuration files in their own folder or in a user folder, like `C:\Users\YourUsername\AppData\Roaming\Sublime...`. Is this problem occurring in both Windows and Linux on the same machine? Are the working installations the exact same version?

Comment: Well you gave me an idea, I reloaded the file and noticed that the changes where visible for like half a second then it went back to the theme's default, so I saved my changes into a new file and loaded that instead and it's working now heh.

Comment: Thanks for giving me some perspective

Comment: I'm glad you found a workaround. But is Sublime Text itself rewriting the configuration file? Are you changing them with the program running?

Comment: Its not being overwritten and yes I'm accessing them with a package within sublime, PackageResourceViewer (I'm not very sure of the name), this package is recommended to easily edit theme files. When I reloaded the file  it never changed, even closed it and reopened it and it had the same values but it just doesnt use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saved changes made to .tmTheme into a new file with "Save as.." using a different name and all the changes are now reflecting properly. Thanks Andrew for giving me a different perspective.

Had to save again as a new file to change it to the settings I wanted to, didn't have this problem with my workplace laptop, going to look into it and see if there is a better solution and post it here, meanwhile this is a way around this problem.